# How to get result from TSQL to JavaSCript using old classic ASP page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, t-sql, asp-classic

We have a classic ASP page which has the below vbscript.

1) invoiceResult is a VB Array
2) invoiceSql: stored proc on SQL server
3) ricoh is company library which I cannot change (no access)

```
invoiceResult = ricoh.storedproc(invoiceSql)
```

Question: I need a javascript array instead of vb6. It does not matter how I get it. Can I somehow transform a vb6 array to a javascript array?
Or can I use Ajax to get SQL data from classic ASP?

Comment: I would just use JQuery and make an ajax call.

Comment: Are you sure there's VB6 involved here? Not VBScript?

Comment: If I ignore the vb6 part, I'd suggest using `Response.Write` to write out the data in the array in proper JavaScript format. In other words, use VBScript to write your JavaScript, the same way as you'd use VBScript to write your html. I don't get along with JavaScript, though, so I can't be bothered to figure out the proper syntax for arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can access VBScript code from JavaScript. Somethin like this might work:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT">
 Function makeArrayVB()
   ' Creates a VBScript array
   dim anArray(1,1)
   anArray(0,0) = "0,0"
   anArray(0,1) = "0,1"
   anArray(1,0) = "1,0"
   anArray(1,1) = "1,1"
   makeArrayVB = anArray
 End Function

 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
 // Accesses a VBScript array within a JScript script
 function getVBArray()
 {
   var arrayObj;
   var jsArray;
   arrayObj = makeArrayVB();
   jsArray = VBArray(arrayObj).toArray();
   alert("VBScript array length = " + jsArray.length);
   // Displays the contents of the array
   for(i=1;i<=jsArray.length;i++)
   {
     alert(jsArray[i-1]);
   }
 }
 </SCRIPT>
```